# What difference does it make when I have line breaks in the source HTML inside element markup?

Tags: html, html-lists

The first code-This is code 1 that I did for my nested list example.
The second code which is different according to how the list is nested but gives the exact same output.
Which should we use and is there a error with using one method over the other?

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>
    B
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>
        B2
        <ul>
          <li>
            B2A
            <ul>
              <li>B2aa</li>
              <li>B2ab</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>B2b</li>
          <li>B2c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        B3
        <ol>
          <li>B31</li>
          <li>B32</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
    <ol>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
      <ul>
       <li>B2a</li>
        <ul>
          <li>B2aa</li>
          <li>B2ab</li>
        </ul>
       <li>B2b</li>
       <li>B2c</li>
      </ul>
    <li>B3</li>
    <ol>
      <li>B31</li>
      <li>B32</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

I tried the second code and i got the exact same output.

Comment: to get reliable rendering across HTML engines you should not make `ol` and `ul` a child of `ol` and `ul` but a child of `li`, like code-1, and it is semantic more clear where the sub list belongs to

Comment: you can create probably the same look with tables or flex-grid, or even styled `div`s but that complete looses the meaning of the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're different when you use different values of [the CSS `white-space` property](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-text/#white-space-property). Quoting from the HTML spec:

> This property specifies two things:
>
> - whether and how [white space](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-text/#white-space) is collapsed
> - whether lines may [wrap](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-text/#wrapping) at unforced [soft wrap opportunities](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-text/#soft-wrap-opportunity)

See for yourself:

```html
<h1>white-space: normal</h1>
<blockquote>This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space into a single character (or in some cases, no character). Lines may wrap at allowed soft wrap opportunities, as determined by the line-breaking rules in effect, in order to minimize inline-axis overflow.</blockquote>

<h2>line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: normal;">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>
    B
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>
        B2
        <ul>
          <li>
            B2A
            <ul>
              <li>B2aa</li>
              <li>B2ab</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>B2b</li>
          <li>B2c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        B3
        <ol>
          <li>B31</li>
          <li>B32</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2>no line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: normal;">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
    <ol>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
      <ul>
       <li>B2a</li>
        <ul>
          <li>B2aa</li>
          <li>B2ab</li>
        </ul>
       <li>B2b</li>
       <li>B2c</li>
      </ul>
    <li>B3</li>
    <ol>
      <li>B31</li>
      <li>B32</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>white-space: pre</h1>
<blockquote>This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Segment breaks such as line feeds are preserved as forced line breaks. Lines only break at forced line breaks; content that does not fit within the block container overflows it.</blockquote>

<h2>line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: pre;">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>
    B
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>
        B2
        <ul>
          <li>
            B2A
            <ul>
              <li>B2aa</li>
              <li>B2ab</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>B2b</li>
          <li>B2c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        B3
        <ol>
          <li>B31</li>
          <li>B32</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2>no line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: pre">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
    <ol>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
      <ul>
       <li>B2a</li>
        <ul>
          <li>B2aa</li>
          <li>B2ab</li>
        </ul>
       <li>B2b</li>
       <li>B2c</li>
      </ul>
    <li>B3</li>
    <ol>
      <li>B31</li>
      <li>B32</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>white-space: nowrap</h1>
<blockquote>Like normal, this value collapses white space; but like pre, it does not allow wrapping.</blockquote>

<h2>line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>
    B
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>
        B2
        <ul>
          <li>
            B2A
            <ul>
              <li>B2aa</li>
              <li>B2ab</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>B2b</li>
          <li>B2c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        B3
        <ol>
          <li>B31</li>
          <li>B32</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2>no line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
    <ol>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
      <ul>
       <li>B2a</li>
        <ul>
          <li>B2aa</li>
          <li>B2ab</li>
        </ul>
       <li>B2b</li>
       <li>B2c</li>
      </ul>
    <li>B3</li>
    <ol>
      <li>B31</li>
      <li>B32</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>white-space: pre-wrap</h1>
<blockquote>Like pre, this value preserves white space; but like normal, it allows wrapping.</blockquote>

<h2>line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>
    B
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>
        B2
        <ul>
          <li>
            B2A
            <ul>
              <li>B2aa</li>
              <li>B2ab</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>B2b</li>
          <li>B2c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        B3
        <ol>
          <li>B31</li>
          <li>B32</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2>no line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
    <ol>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
      <ul>
       <li>B2a</li>
        <ul>
          <li>B2aa</li>
          <li>B2ab</li>
        </ul>
       <li>B2b</li>
       <li>B2c</li>
      </ul>
    <li>B3</li>
    <ol>
      <li>B31</li>
      <li>B32</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>white-space: break-spaces</h1>
<blockquote>The behavior is identical to that of pre-wrap, except that:
Any sequence of preserved white space or other space separators always takes up space, including at the end of the line.
A soft wrap opportunity exists after every preserved white space character and after every other space separator (including between adjacent spaces).</blockquote>

<h2>line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: break-spaces;">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>
    B
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>
        B2
        <ul>
          <li>
            B2A
            <ul>
              <li>B2aa</li>
              <li>B2ab</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>B2b</li>
          <li>B2c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        B3
        <ol>
          <li>B31</li>
          <li>B32</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2>no line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: break-spaces">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
    <ol>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
      <ul>
       <li>B2a</li>
        <ul>
          <li>B2aa</li>
          <li>B2ab</li>
        </ul>
       <li>B2b</li>
       <li>B2c</li>
      </ul>
    <li>B3</li>
    <ol>
      <li>B31</li>
      <li>B32</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>white-space: pre-line</h1>
<blockquote>Like normal, this value collapses consecutive white space characters and allows wrapping, but it preserves segment breaks in the source as forced line breaks.</blockquote>

<h2>line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: pre-line;">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>
    B
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>
        B2
        <ul>
          <li>
            B2A
            <ul>
              <li>B2aa</li>
              <li>B2ab</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>B2b</li>
          <li>B2c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        B3
        <ol>
          <li>B31</li>
          <li>B32</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<h2>no line breaks inside source elements</h2>
<div style="white-space: pre-line">
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
    <ol>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
      <ul>
       <li>B2a</li>
        <ul>
          <li>B2aa</li>
          <li>B2ab</li>
        </ul>
       <li>B2b</li>
       <li>B2c</li>
      </ul>
    <li>B3</li>
    <ol>
      <li>B31</li>
      <li>B32</li>
    </ol>
    </ol>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>
```

Use whichever one works for your site. As you can see, for `white-space: normal`, there's no difference, in which case it doesn't matter. Even if you have a *lot* of whitespace that doesn't get rendered, as long as you use [compression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Compression), it shouldn't affect the page fetch time much.